# XStream - How can I treat HTML tags as content, rather than fields?

Tags: java, xstream

I've got some XML that contains HTML tags in the content of a particular field, abstract, for example:

```
<abstract>
<p>
Kringles are autonomous structural domains, found throughout the blood clotting and fibrinolytic proteins. Kringle domains are believed to play a role in binding mediators (e.g., membranes, other proteins or phospholipids), and in the regulation of proteolytic activity [<cite idref="PUB00002414"/>, <cite idref="PUB00001541"/>, <cite idref="PUB00003257"/>].
</p>
<p>
Kringle domains [<cite idref="PUB00003400"/>, <cite idref="PUB00000803"/>, <cite idref="PUB00001620"/>] are characterised by a triple loop, 3-disulphide bridge structure, whose  conformation is defined by a number of hydrogen bonds and small pieces of  anti-parallel beta-sheet. They are found in a varying number  of  copies  in some plasma proteins including prothrombin and urokinase-type plasminogen activator, which are serine proteases belonging to MEROPS peptidase family S1A.
</p>
</abstract>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to tell XStream to simply ignore these HTML and cite tags (not "ignore" in the sense of "omit," which is what XStream.ignoreUnknownElements() or XStream.omitField() do).

I'd like to just pull the entire abstract content into a string, including the HTML and cite tags.

Appreciate any suggestions!!!